# How to hide cells of a single column on mouseleave on Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to use Jquery to hide the second column (.capital) and show each individual cell of that column on mouseenter and hide them back on mouseleave

It's kinda like this: http://macloo.github.io/jquery_exercises/states.html except that it should work only on the second column

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>States Table: jQuery Exercise</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/states.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/exStates.js"></script>
    
</head>

<table id="states">
    <tr>
        <th class="columnhead"> State </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Capital </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Largest City </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Bird </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Flower </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Alabama </th>
        <td class="capital"> <span>Montgomery</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Birmingham</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Yellowhammer</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Camellia</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Alaska </th>
        <td class="capital"> <span>Juneau</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Anchorage</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Willow Ptarmigan</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Forget-me-not</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Arizona </th>
        <td class="capital"> <span>Phoenix</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Phoenix</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Cactus Wren</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Saguaro Cactus Blossom</span> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My Jquery so far is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 

    $('.capital').find('td').addClass('column-bar');
    $('.capital').find('td').hide();
    
    
    $('.capital').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'td', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('column-bar');
        $(this).toggle();
    });
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to hide/show capital, do you have to just play with the class `capital` and `span`:

```
  $('.capital').addClass('column-bar');
  $('.capital span').hide();


  $('.capital').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('column-bar');
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. But I'm not sure whether you want the mouseenter to operate at the level of the table or the column. If it's at the level of the column, then as soon as it disappears, the mouse will have left it already, which is kind of odd.

```js
$('#states').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
   $(this).find('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').toggle();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>States Table: jQuery Exercise</title>
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
</head>

<body>

<table id="states">
    <tr>
        <th class="columnhead"> State </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Capital </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Largest City </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Bird </th>
        <th class="columnhead"> Flower </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Alabama </th>
        <td> <span>Montgomery</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Birmingham</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Yellowhammer</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Camellia</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Alaska </th>
        <td> <span>Juneau</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Anchorage</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Willow Ptarmigan</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Forget-me-not</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Arizona </th>
        <td> <span>Phoenix</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Phoenix</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Cactus Wren</span> </td>
        <td> <span>Saguaro Cactus Blossom</span> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.capital').find('td').addClass('column-bar');
    $('.capital').find('td').hide();    
    
    $('.capital').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('column-bar');
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```